# Stack two arrays using hstack. Vertically stack the result with a third array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I would appreciate guidance on how to do this:

Horizontally stack two arrays using hstack, and finally, vertically stack the resultant array with the third array.

```
input_list = [[[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[3, 4], [7, 8]], [[9, 10, 11, 12]]]
```

Please have a look at the issue as mentioned in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
a = np.array(([1,2],[5,6]))
b = np.array(([3,4],[7,8]))
c = np.array([9,10,11,12])

h = np.hstack((a,b))

result = np.vstack((h,c))
```

Arrays **a,b,c** are inputs.
First **a** and **b** are horizontally stacked with *hstack()*. The resulting array, **h**, is then vertically stacked with **c** by using *vstack()* instead.

In your case:

```
input_list = [[[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[3, 4], [7, 8]], [[9, 10, 11, 12]]]
a = input_list[0]
b = input_list[1]
c = input_list[2]

h = np.hstack((a,b))

result = np.vstack((h,c))
```

Edit:

- hstack doc here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html
- vstack doc: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur support and cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Another soluation:

Please have a look at this picture as mentioned here.